# Floating boxes won't float when printing

Tags: css, printing, css-float

Is it just me or do browsers have real trouble printing pages that have floating (column) layouts?

For example, the following HTML+CSS will output drastically different results on screen versus on paper:

### CSS:

```
/* Dead Simple Grid (c) 2012 Vladimir Agafonkin */

.col {
    padding: 0 1.5em;
}
.row .row {
    margin: 0 -1.5em;
}

.row:before, .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}

@media only screen {
    .col {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}

/* Personal style addons */

section.col {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.c50 {
    width: 20%;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <section class="col c50">
        <h1>A bizarrely long heading that should work.</h1>
    </section>
    <section class="col c50">
        <p>Climb leg rub face on everything give attitude nap all day for under the bed. Chase mice attack feet but rub face on everything hopped up on goofballs.</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y675e/. As you can clearly see there are two columns.

Now when I go to http://jsfiddle.net/Y675e/show and view it in browser, it's still two columns.

But when I **print out** that same page, I get something of this sort:

[image: It doesn't float?]

So it seems that the floating layout has disappeared. But it's not the issue that the `<div>`s are too wide. They are only 20% of the screen width, and should fit on the same 'line'. How would I go about fixing this printing issue?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Notice the media query on col:

```
@media only screen {
    .col {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;

        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}
```

You have to get rid of the `only screen` part, otherwise the `.col`s won't float at all.